# Skipping last row on a CSV file with logic apps

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

I have received a blob containing a CSV file. Is there a way to skip the last row since they do not require parsing?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use compose connector with substring() expression. Here is an example

[image]

- After receiving the csv file try to read the last index of '\n' and then use substring.
  Expression of lastIndexOf() in `compose2` Connector:

  ```
  lastIndexOf(body('Get_blob_content_(V2)'),'\n')
  ```
- Since you are adding '\n' in `lastIndexOf` the logic app takes it as '\n'. Hence you need to go to your code view and change it to '\n' resulting:

  ```
  lastIndexOf(body('Get_blob_content_(V2)'),'

  ')
  ```
- Expression of substring() in `compose` Connector

  ```
  substring(body('Get_blob_content_(V2)'),0,outputs('Compose_2'))
  ```
- you can even write it together as

  ```
  substring(body('Get_blob_content_(V2)'),0,lastIndexOf(body('Get_blob_content_(V2)'),'

  '))
  ```